# Sorting multiple-line records in alphabetical order using shell

Tags: shell, sorting, text-processing

There is a file which has the following structure:

```
L. feritas
E. ferity

L. ars
E. art

L. solitudo
E. solitude

L. celeritas
E. celerity
```

Each line is a field, and a record spans multiple lines, comprising an `L.` field, an `E.` field, and a blank line. How can I sort the records by the fields that are tagged `L.`, keeping the multiple-line records intact?

```
L. ars
E. art

L. celeritas
E. celerity

L. feritas
E. ferity

L. solitudo
E. solitude
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick way of coming up with something is:

```
$ cat file | awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1' \
  | sort | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="\n";ORS="\n\n"}{$1=$1}1'
```

Or you can write it in a single Gnu AWK,

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"}
       {a[NR]=$0}END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file
```

If you don't want the last line to be empty, you can do the following:

```
$ cat file | awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1' \
  | sort | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="\n"}{$1=$1}1' | sed '$d'


$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS=OFS="\n"; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"}
       {a[NR]=$0}END{for(i in a) print a[i] (--NR?"\n":"")}' file
```

Comment: The second one would remove duplicates if there were any. You could still use gawk sorting with something like `a[NR] = $0` and `END{asort(a); ...}`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I have added an updated version. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: It works perfectly except one thing: the last line of the file is blank.

Comment: Thanks! What about the first solution?

Comment: @J.Doe if this answered your question, have a look at [Someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)